# Where is the project wizard in VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, static-libraries

I want to create a static library which I want to use in other projects in VS2017 Community but I can't find the right way.
I tried to follow the instructions from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx#BKMK_CreateLibProject) which is for VS2015 but when I want to create a new project I can just provide the name, solution name, location of solution and whether I want to create a directory for the solution or not and with git repository or not.

I remember a project wizard where I could deselect precompiled headers and set the output to a static library.

Did something change or am I missing a component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Create new project and under `Visual C++ -> Windows Desktop` there is a project template called `Windows Desktop Wizard` which will open the project wizard.

From [VS 2017 15.3 Release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes) (credits to user [VTT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46400153/846641) from another question)

> The Windows Console and Desktop Application templates now create the projects without displaying a wizard. There's a new Windows Desktop Wizard under the same category that displays the same options as before.