# Visual Studio 2017 console application : precompiled header

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Recently I updated my Visual Studio 2017.
Since then, I can't create windows console application project.

**[File] - [New] - [Project]**

and I selected **[Installed] - [visual C++] - [windows console application program]**

When I clicked OK, application setting wizard didn't appear.

[image: wizard]

above wizard didn't appear. Instead Visual Studio automatically created precompiled header project.

[image: stdafx]

What's wrong?

Comment: When installing, you were sure to check the "Universal Windows Platform development” and “Desktop development with C++” boxes, right?

Comment: yes, I did. I resolved that issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Visual Studio 2017 release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes):

> The Windows Console and Desktop Application templates now create the projects without displaying a wizard. There's a new Windows Desktop Wizard under the same category that displays the same options as before.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my issue.

**Go to file -> new project -> visual c++ -> windows desktop -> windows desktop wizard**

Answer (score 1):

> There's a new Windows Desktop Wizard under the same category that displays the same options as before

[image: Windows Desktop Wizard under]

Be sure you selected ... ***Wizard*** by creating project. There you can select "Console Application" type , DLL... in drop down menu. If you have selected "Windows Console Application" for instance there is no wizard any more, it creates full project. You can set/change that under:

**Configuration Properties → C++ → Precompiled Headers**

Answer (score 0):

if you need to have an empty console application project, try empty project.
[Installed] - [visual C++] - [Empty Project].
Then add new .cpp file to the Source Files folder in solution explorer.
[right click on Source Files] - [Add New Item] - [C++ File (.cpp)].